# JQuery returns DOM element when I haven't imported it but an object when I have

Tags: jquery, object, dom, import

Not totally new to this but it's been a loooong time.

I load a simple page in Firefox with no JS at all. It has the body:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="goButton">GO</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Open the console and I can experiment with JS and JQuery. I type:

```
$(".goButton")
```

And I see the button DOM element in the console. Furthermore I can use the innerHTML property to retrieve the string "GO".

I then add JQuery to my page thusly:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="goButton">GO</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Open the console and do the same thing with the go button and it now returns an object, not a DOM element. Furthermore of course the innerHTML is undefined.

What's changed here?

Comment: When you don't include jquery, add this line `console.log($)` - that will tell you what `$` is defined to before you overwrite it with jquery.  When you do include jquery, `$==jQuery` - so you're making calls to jquery and returning a jquery collection/object.

Comment: Note that some browsers include a `$` shortcut for you in the console for when you haven't installed jquery or some other framework that defines `$` - try adding it to your *code* instead of in the browser console, ie `<script>console.log($(".goButton"))</script>` - you'll probably get error $ isn't defined